# Remove choices before render the widget

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using DoctrineEnumBundle from Fresh and I have this type defined:

```
namespace CommonBundle\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Fresh\Bundle\DoctrineEnumBundle\DBAL\Types\AbstractEnumType;

class AdminRoleType extends AbstractEnumType
{

    const ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
    const ROLE_GERENTE = "ROLE_GERENTE";
    const ROLE_FISCAL = "ROLE_FISCAL";
    const ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO = "ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO";
    const ROLE_OPERADOR = "ROLE_OPERADOR";

    /**
     * @var string Name of this type
     */
    protected $name = 'AdminRoleType';

    /**
     * @var array Readable choices
     * @static
     */
    protected static $choices = [
        self::ROLE_ADMIN => 'Administrador',
        self::ROLE_GERENTE => 'Gerente',
        self::ROLE_FISCAL => 'Fiscal',
        self::ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO => 'Centro Hípico',
        self::ROLE_OPERADOR => 'Operadora'
    ];

}
```

Then in my form type I have a field like this:

```
....
->add('roleType', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => AdminRoleType::getChoices(),
    'required' => true,
    'label' => "User Type",
    'trim' => true
))
....
```

In one view I need to render just `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_OPERADOR` but in another view I need to render all of them, how I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my issue, just need to add as many methods as I want to return what I need, see the example below:

```
class RoleType extends AbstractEnumType
{
    const ROLE_ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";
    const ROLE_GERENTE = "ROLE_GERENTE";
    const ROLE_FISCAL = "ROLE_FISCAL";
    const ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO = "ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO";
    const ROLE_OPERADOR = "ROLE_OPERADOR";

    /**
     * @var string Name of this type
     */
    protected $name = 'RoleType';

    /**
     * @var array Readable choices
     * @static
     */
    protected static $choices = [
        self::ROLE_ADMIN => 'Administrador',
        self::ROLE_GERENTE => 'Gerente',
        self::ROLE_FISCAL => 'Fiscal',
        self::ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO => 'Centro Hípico',
        self::ROLE_OPERADOR => 'Operadora'
    ];

    public static function getFrontChoices()
    {
        return [
            self::ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO => 'Centro Hípico',
            self::ROLE_OPERADOR => 'Operadora'
        ];
    }
}
```

Then at form if I want just to show `ROLE_CENTRO_HIPICO` and `ROLE_OPERADOR` instead of call `getChoices()` I call `getFrontChoices()`:

```
....
->add('roleType', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => AdminRoleType::getFrontChoices(),
    'required' => true,
    'label' => "User Type",
    'trim' => true
))
....
```

That's all